# Loop doesn't stop on return?

Tags: php

I checked with x-debug, when the condition `$form_id === $element['id']` is met, the loop should be stopped but it jumps to this line `if ( $element )`. What is the cavet here?

```php
public function find_element_recursive( $elements, $form_id ) {
    foreach ( $elements as $element ) {

        if ( $form_id === $element['id'] ) {
            return $element;
        }

        if ( ! empty( $element['elements'] ) ) {
            $element = self::find_element_recursive( $element['elements'], $form_id );

            if ( $element ) {
                return $element;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's returning from the recursive call, then going to that line in the caller.

Comment: You didn't notice that you were in different levels of recursion

Comment: @Barmar I didn't get you properly.

Comment: When you do `$element = self::find_element_recursive(...);` it calls the function again. That instance returns, then you execute `if ($element)` in the first instance.

Comment: Oh. Right. How dumb I am. I couldn't notice. Thanks.